# Capistrano has incorrect default deploy location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy using Capistrano 3.1.0.

The file `deploy.rb` states:

`# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app`

However, when I run `cap production deploy` I get the following error:

`mkdir: cannot create directory /var/www/shared`

It appears to be ignoring my app name completely and trying to create directories in the wrong place. It should be trying to create `/var/www/myapp/shared/`. My `deploy.rb` file specifically has:

`set :application, 'myapp'`

Am I missing something here, or is this a bug?

**UPDATE:** The relevant line of the Capistrano source code appears to be:

`set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{fetch(:application)}"`

in `defaults.rb`. If I print out the value of `fetch(:application)` it's `nil`, so something is stopping my application name from being set properly.

Comment: you're right, it should be creating /var/www/myapp/shared. Can you try using double quotes rather than single and chaging the application name to something more descriptive. This is totally a guess btw.  set :application, "rails_application".

Comment: Still failed with double quotes. The relevant line in the Capistrano source (I think) is: `set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{fetch(:application)}"`. If I print out the value of `fetch(:application)` it's `nil`, which is a problem and would explain what I'm seeing...

Comment: `set :deploy_to "/var/www/#{application}"` after setting application

Comment: @Vimsha I'm guessing that would work, but that should be the default value, right? Why should I be manually setting it to the value it should already have?

Comment: deploy_to isn't a default setting. I checked all my projects and I am setting that. set :application => "app"; set :deploy_to "/var/www/#{application}"

Comment: @aardvarkk: I can't find any documentation that says deploy_to is set to `/var/www` by default. In fact it defaults to `/u/apps/$app_name` -> https://gist.github.com/jrochkind/2161449#path-on-target-server

Comment: This is Capistrano version 3.1.0. Make sure you're not referencing v2.x of Capistrano. The file `deploy.rb` explicitly states `# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app`. This also jives with the code inside the Capistrano library that I posted above that tries to set it to the application name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the directory structure that Capistrano requires. You can use the Capistrano itself to create it with the command:

```
cap deploy:setup
```

Or you can create it directly with something like this:

```
# Capistrano will use /var/www/....... where ... is the value set in
# :application, you can override this by setting the ':deploy_to' variable
deploy_to=/var/www/:application
mkdir -p ${deploy_to}
mkdir ${deploy_to}/{releases,shared}
```

ref.: wiki [deploy:setup](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks#wiki-deploysetup) and [Authentication and Authorisation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/)

edit: if you set the `:deploy_to` **after** the `:application`, you don't need the [commit](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/commit/fcc3aef367f8e83fe85cfded6658cbb99912e8fd) you [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22183276/1531208).

Comment: The commit is still required: The default :deploy_to is set inside of Capistrano's source code and must be changed by them. Same goes for the ordering -- that's controlled by Capistrano. Other than overriding the default (which I don't feel is correct), the new commit is the best solution. Although it's not yet available in a release, you can get the latest gem from git and it includes the required change.

Comment: @aardvarkk strange, I've looked in all my `deploy.rb` files and they all set the `:application` name **before** the `:deploy_to` and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a bug with a fix that hasn't yet made it into a release.

Here's the change:

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/defaults.rb#L3

Comment: updated my answer to show how to resolve until the commit is released.